# how to print file C#

Tags: c#, printing

I wonder how to print any printable document such as doc/docx/txt/pdf using C# (WPF/WinForm whatever). MSDN documentation shows how to print .txt files (like this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). But when i'm trying to print .docx i've got XML-like text. I need to print file from directory only. I don't want to edit it etc. So i wonder i can skip few steps and send my file to printer directly, can't i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var pd = new PrintDialog())  
            {  
                pd.ShowDialog();  
                var info = new ProcessStartInfo()  
                {  
                    Verb = "print",  
                    CreateNoWindow = true,  
                    FileName = @"D:\Desktop\00762.pdf",  
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden  
                };  
                Process.Start(info);  
            }
```